# FPDF Import Error: cannot import name 'FPDF' from 'fpdf' (unknown location)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, fpdf

I'm using Python 3.8.5, conda 4.10.3 and FPDF2  2.3.1

When I try to import the package, I get the following error:

Input:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
```

Response:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/q3/38dtckns13b368s1x7g59hh40000gn/T/ipykernel_917/4051462934.py in <module>
----> 1 from fpdf import FPDF

ImportError: cannot import name 'FPDF' from 'fpdf' (unknown location)
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled FPDF2 several times, both from PyPI `pip install fpdf2` and from anaconda  `conda install -c conda-forge fpdf2`.

Installation is successfull but code keeps running with errors.

Comment: _I have uninstalled and reinstalled FPDF2 several times_ Wouldn't the imported package name be `fpdf2`, not `fpdf`?

Comment: I checked but no, its supposed to be imported as fpdf. I also tried importing as fpdf2 with no success.

Answer (score 3):

Try to uninstall the module through this command:

```
pip uninstall fpdf2
```

then again install the module with this command:

```
pip install fpdf2
```

Hope this will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

### The solution is here:

Step1 : `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

Step2 : 'python -m pip uninstall fpdf'

Step3 : `python -m pip install fpdf`

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem downloading fpdf from pip, instead of Anaconda, after being adviced by the fpdf team.